# Opening Material UI Modal from a parent within a parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a table with a list of teams; the last column in each row opens up a menu, and I want the menu items to open up a modal or a dialog, depending on the item. I want to keep the table, menu, and modal as separate components. So it looks like this:

`Teams.tsx`

```
const testDataTeams = [
  { name: 'Cincinatti Bengals', owner: 'John Person', created: '11/11/11', members: 4 },
  { name: 'Los Angeles Rams', owner: 'John Person', created: '11/11/11', members: 3 },
  { name: 'The A-Team', owner: 'John Person', created: '11/11/11', members: 2 },
]

export default function Teams() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const [openModal, setOpen] = React.useState(null);
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const moreOptions = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
      setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const clickModal = Boolean(openModal)
    const closeModal = () => {
      setOpen(null)
    };
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
    <Table sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'table', lg: 'table' }, minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <StyledTableCell>Name</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right">Owner</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right">Date&nbsp;Created</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right">Members</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right"></StyledTableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {testDataTeams.map((item) => (
          <StyledTableRow key={item.name}>
            <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">{item.name}</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.owner}</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.created}</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.members}</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">
              <IconButton 
                id="basic-button"
                aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                onClick={moreOptions}>
                <MoreIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu
                id="basic-menu"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                MenuListProps={{
                  'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
                }}
              >
                <TeamMenu clickModal={clickModal} closeModal={closeModal} />
              </Menu>
            </StyledTableCell>
          </StyledTableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

`TeamMenu.tsx`

```
export default function TeamMenu(clickModal, closeModal) {
    return (
        <div>
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <NotificationsIcon fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText>Notification Settings</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={closeModal}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <EditIcon fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText>Edit Team Info</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
        <TeamsModal open={clickModal} handleClose={closeModal} />
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <GroupIcon fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText>Edit Members</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText>Delete Team</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
        </div>
  );
}
```

`TeamsModal.tsx`

```
const TeamsModal = ({ open, handleClose }) => {
  return (
    <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
            Text in a modal
          </Typography>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
            Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
  )
}

export default TeamsModal;
```

I can get props to pass to the Team Menu, but I'm having trouble getting it down another level, and I'm worried I've made my code too convoluted. What would be the best way to execute this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback function to the `TeamsMenu` component like you are doing here, but it doesn't look like you are returning the actual `TeamsModal` component in the `Teams` component.

You want to have the `TeamsModal` in the `Teams` component like so:

```
const testDataTeams = [
  { name: 'Cincinatti Bengals', owner: 'John Person', created: '11/11/11', members: 4 },
  { name: 'Los Angeles Rams', owner: 'John Person', created: '11/11/11', members: 3 },
  { name: 'The A-Team', owner: 'John Person', created: '11/11/11', members: 2 },
]

export default function Teams() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const [openModal, setOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const moreOptions = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
      setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const clickModal = () => setOpen(true);
    const closeModal = () => setOpen(false);
  return (
<>
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
    <Table sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'table', lg: 'table' }, minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <StyledTableCell>Name</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right">Owner</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right">Date&nbsp;Created</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right">Members</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right"></StyledTableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {testDataTeams.map((item) => (
          <StyledTableRow key={item.name}>
            <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">{item.name}</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.owner}</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.created}</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.members}</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">
              <IconButton 
                id="basic-button"
                aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                onClick={moreOptions}>
                <MoreIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu
                id="basic-menu"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                MenuListProps={{
                  'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
                }}
              >
                <TeamMenu clickModal={clickModal} closeModal={closeModal} />
              </Menu>
            </StyledTableCell>
          </StyledTableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
 {openModal && (
  <TeamsModal open={openModal} handleClose={() => setOpen(false)} />
)}
</>
  );
}
```

Notice that I defined the state type for open as boolean instead of using null.

This ensures the modal will open when the `openModal` state is set to true.

Also, if you are using Typescript I recommend you define types for components and props to ensure you aren't making silly mistakes and have that sweet autocomplete capability.

Comment: How do I then have the modal open from the TeamMenu?